# Android Studio 0.5.8 and Gradle to work offline after gradle zip is downloaded

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I've installed a fresh version of Android Studio and from there created a new application. It created my file but the Gradle causes me a lot of problem. For the whole day straight it always try to download the gradle-1.10-all.zip but as always it fails.

Message is:

Gradle:Download http://services.gradle/org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip

Hope they decide to add up some progress bar for this. LOL

I'm in doubt that this is due to internet connection just to take note. Although I'm investigating about the possible solution via HTTP proxy.

Now for an alternate solution I tried to download the whole zip file instead from http://www.gradle.org/downloads. While I successfully downloaded and extracted the whole zip file. Then from android Studio I tried setting the Global Gradle Settings into offline work and as well as the Project-level settings into: use local gradle distribution and mapped the extracted zip file (although I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this)

Does anyone know on how should I do the workarounds for this?

Hope that maybe someone can help me work with this or someone who already solved this issue since for now I don't have a plan to update from this version anymore given that each and everytime that the Android Studio updates it was always been a pain in the ass and Second I need to work on most of my projects offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the solution on this. First you need to download the whole zip file from: `http://www.gradle.org/downloads`

Next step is to just let the Android Studio Create the folder for the .gradle in your User then from there you can just halt the project initialization and then go to the location of the .gradle folder. In my case it's:

```
C:\Users\USER\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.10-all\SOME_SORT_OF_STRING
```

Just copy and paste the whole zip file on the location (no need to unzip the file). Also you have to make sure it has the same version with the one in your gradle wrapper folder which in my case is gradle-1.10-all.

Try restarting the Android Studio. You can create a new project once again and let it extract the zip file. It should now start on downloading the other files needed and from here you will need a reliable and stable internet connection. The succeeding files will have a smaller size compared to the zip package but in my case since I don't have a stable connection I used to tether my mobile phone instead and viola! Android Studio installation is now complete and running.

Answer (score 0):

There exist options for offline working.

On command line add --offline option to your gradle command.

In Android studio you can set this option in the setting on the gradle configuration part. Just check the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing is to find a friend that is already started using the studio, You can copy .gradle ,. androidstudio/.androidstudiobeta and .android directories in your user directory. If gradel is your only problem just copy that one only.